# Acid Properties in Hive

Tags: hive, data-warehouse, orc, bigdata

Just wanted to know if it is possible to run acid transactions on a table that is stored in textfile format in hive. I know we can store a table in text file format and create a new table with orc format and insert data into it using textfile table. Is there any other approach that reduces this overhead ?

Comment: In Hive, ACID transactions applies on a row level. not a table level.

Comment: From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations : Only ORC file format is supported. You can create ORC files also by writing a custom MR job.